# Third-Party Child Component doesn't change on Props change from Parent in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Am using a third party component to render a tree-table and its a normal flow with parent calling the Child component by passing the required Props.

Props : 
1. tree ( contains the actual data to be rendered as tree )
2. sortOrder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TreeDataTable from 'cp-react-tree-table';

    class TreeView extends Component {
        static propTypes = {
          tree: PropTypes.array,
          sortOrd:PropTypes.any
        };

        static defaultProps = {
            tree: [],
            height: 0
        };

        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.table = React.createRef();
          this.state = {
            sortOrder: ''
          };
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.tableRef(this.table);
        }
        componentWillReceiveProps({sortOrd}){
            this.setState({sortOrder:sortOrd});
        }

        render() {
          const { tree } = this.props;
          return (
            <div className="treeview">
            // data attribute passes the data to form tree
              <TreeDataTable ref={this.table} data={tree} className="treeview-body">
                <TreeDataTable.Column basis="80%" renderCell={this.renderIndexColumn} />
              </TreeDataTable>
            </div>
          );
        }
```

Am trying to re-order the tree-table based on a button-click (consequent state change) in parent component.

**What works :**
1. State changes in the parent component
2. Parent component re-renders
3. calls the child component with updated props ( data, sortOrder )

4. Child component is invoked
5. Child component state changes based on the updated props
6. Child component re-renders

**Issue:**
Child component re-renders with old props ( data )

**Expected result:**
Child component to re-render with updated props ( data )

As a normal Child component , this should have worked, but since am using a third party component, I doubt there is something am missing to make it re-render with the updated data.

Is there a way , I could make this child component re-render with the updated props( data ) and show the updated Tree.

Answer (score 0):

componentWillReceiveProps gives you nextProps but you are getting it as an object

Change

```
     componentWillReceiveProps({sortOrd}){
           this.setState({sortOrder:sortOrd});
     }
```

To

```
     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
           if(nextProps.sortOrd != this.props.sortOrd){          
                  this.setState({sortOrder:sortOrd});

            }
       }
```

But keep in mind that componentWillReceiveProps life cycle method is deprecated so alternative life cycle method is

```
     static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
          if(nextProps.sortOrd != this.props.sortOrd){
                 return {
                      sortOrder : nextProps.sortOrd //this is equivalent to setState
                 };
            }else{
                 return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: But the issue is not setting the state. Am already able to do that. Issue is         <TreeDataTable >  is not re-rendering with updated data ( updated props )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in componentWillReceiveProps,setState in componentWillReceiveProps will causes the state update but won't invoke render.Maybe you can set sortOrder like below,and pass null first.

```
constructor(props) {
      ...
      this.state = {
        sortOrder: props.sortOrd
      };
    }
```

Then, after change props in the father component,tree-table will re-render.

Comment: No.It didn't work.  Actually the state change invokes the render function. But the <TreeDataTable>  holds back the data due to which the component re-renders with same data.

Comment: Could you share which third party do you use?@Dexter

Comment: import TreeDataTable from 'cp-react-tree-table'